# Display Dynamic Fields with Radio Buttons in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view in my MVC site that is used for search parameters for a specific page.  In this partial, I am displaying parameters dynamically based on a specific ID number. Some of these parameters need to allow the user to either enter an exact value or a range of values.  This is what I have so far:

```
<form id="DynamicFieldsForm">
    @{
        List<DynamicParameter> ddParams = dal.GetParameters();
        foreach (DynamicParameter dp in ddParams.OrderBy(d => d.ParameterName))
        {
            <div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                    <div class="designerDataParamRangeSelect">
                        <input type="radio" id="@(dp.ParameterID)_RadioExact" value="exact" />Exact<br />
                        <input type="radio" id="@(dp.ParameterID)_RadioRange" value="range" />Range
                    </div>

                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="@(dp.ParameterID)_Lower" name="@(dp.ParameterID)_Lower" placeholder="@dp.ParameterName Lower" value="" @maxLength />
                    <div id="hideThis">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="@(dp.ParameterID)_Upper" name="@(dp.ParameterID)_Upper" placeholder="@dp.ParameterName Upper" value="" @maxLength />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</form>
```

This partial view is also displayed after the specific ID is selected from a dropdown.  I have the UI working... that's not the issue.  What I need help with is how do I display or hide the input field in the `"hideThis"` div when the `"_RadioRange"` radio button is selected.  I am sending these values to a controller from a javascript function and that all works too.  I just need assistance with displaying and hiding of these fields.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: OK I feel a bit stupid now lol.  Every example I looked at had the 'name' attribute and I never tried using that.  Thanks for the input...I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 radio buttons need to have a `name` attribute (both the same) so they are grouped (currently you can select both radio button and cannot unselect either).

However there are multiple other issues with your implementation, including generate invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes), no validation, and including database access code in your view making it near impossible to unit test.

I recommend that you start by creating a `[ChildActionOnly]` method that returns a partial view and in the layout, use `@Html.Action()` to render it. That partial should be based on a view model that allows you to get both client and server side validation, for example

```
public class ParameterVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasRange { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfFalse(ErrorMessage = "...")]
    public int? Value { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfTrue("HasRange", ErrorMessage = "...")]
    public int? LowerLimit { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfTrue("HasRange", ErrorMessage = "...")]
    public int? UpperLimit { get; set; }
}
```

Note the `RequiredIfTrueAttribute` and `RequiredIfFalseAttribute` is from [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/), but you will find plenty of examples of creating conditional attributes on SO.

Your controller method would the be something like

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Parameters()
{
    var model = dal.GetParameters().OrderBy(x => x.ParameterName).Select(x => new ParameterVM()
    {
        Name = x.ParameterName,
        HasRange = ... // set defaults for other properties as required
    }).ToList();
    return PartialView("_Parameters", model);
}
```

and the `_Parameters.cstml` partial view would be

```
@model List<ParameterVM>
<form>
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="parameter">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].HasRange, false, new { id = "", @class = "radio" })
                <span>Exact</span>
            </label>
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].HasRange, true, new { id = "", , @class = "radio" })
                <span>Range</span>
            </label>
            <div class="exact"@(Model.HasRange ? " hidden" ? "")>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Value)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Value)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].Value)
            </div>
            <div class="range@(Model.HasRange ? "" ? " hidden")>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].LowerLimit)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].LowerLimit)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].LowerLimit)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].UpperLimit)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].UpperLimit)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].UpperLimit)
            </div>   
        <div>
    }
</form>
```

And in the layout, include the following script to toggle the visibility of the associated textboxes

```
$('.radio').change(function() {
    var container = $(this).closest('.parameter');
    container.find('.exact').toggleClass('hidden');
    container.find('.range').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what JS frameworks (if any) you were using.  In jQuery, I have a re-usable method that I use frequently for dynamic form display:

JS:

```
var toggleChecked = function() {
        var $this       = $(this),
            $target     = $($this.data('target'))
        ;
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $target.toggle($this.data('display'));
        }
    }
;
$(document).on('click','[data-action=toggleChecked]', toggleChecked);
```

HTML:

```
<input id='myRadio_y' name='myRadio' type='radio' value='1'
    data-action='toggleChecked' data-target='#hideThis' data-display='true' />
<input id='myRadio_n' name='myRadio' type='radio' value='0'
    data-action='toggleChecked' data-target='#hideThis' data-display='false' />

<div id='hideThis'>Dynamically Displayed Field</div>
```

Within a loop, the "hideThis" Id would need to have a unique Id for every iteration of the loop.  You could add an `@(i)` to the end of each ID...something like this:

```
@{ int i = 0; }

foreach(...) {
    <input id='myRadio_y' name='myRadio' type='radio' value='1'
      data-action='toggleChecked' data-target='#hideThis@(i)' data-display='true' />
    <input id='myRadio_n' name='myRadio' type='radio' value='0'
      data-action='toggleChecked' data-target='#hideThis@(i)' data-display='false' />

    <div id='hideThis@(i)'>Dynamically Displayed Field</div>
    i++;
}
```

Explanation:

In the HTML, any checkbox or radio button with data-action="toggleChecked" can toggle the display of another HTML tag.  The data-target specifies the tag to be toggled with a CSS selector, and the data-display="(true|false)" indicated whether that specific radio-button/checkbox should show or hide (respectively).

Let me know if there are any additional details I can help fill-in if this looks like it's on the right track for your question.